# Getting the error " `butter' undefined" in Octave. How to fix it?

Tags: matlab, octave

When I write this line in Octave:

```
[b,a] = butter (5,0.2);
```

I get the error:

> error: `butter' undefined near line 1 column 10

How can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to load the [signal](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/index.html) package. You have to install and load it in order to use the `butter` function:

```
pkg install -forge signal
pkg load signal
[b,a] = butter (5,0.2);
```

Please take a look in the Octave [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/). It explains [how to install](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html) and [how to load](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Using-Packages.html) packages.

Answer (score 2):

The `butter` function is part of the `signal` package. You need to download, install and load the package before you can use its functions:

```
>> pkg install -forge signal
>> pkg load signal
```